# Java Double to BigDecimal Conversion Without E Notation

Tags: java, java-8, double, bigdecimal

In JDK8:

```
   import java.math.BigDecimal;
    public class HelloWorld{
    
         public static void main(String []args){
             Double aDouble=new Double(295699630);
            System.out.println(BigDecimal.valueOf(aDouble.doubleValue()));
           
         }
    }
```

Gives Output: 2.9569963E+8 .
**Number ends with zero (like 295699630,848436700) comes with notation E.** But if number ends with any non zero number then the above code snippet gives us desired output (Number like: 295699631 will not contain 'E' after conversion). What is reason of this & ***how we can avoid scientic notation 'E' in this conversion?*** Need output in BigDecimal format (Not String) without 'E' notation.
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `What is reason of this` The reason is because that's what the makers decided is the appropriate output for the `toString()` function. `how we can avoid scientic notation 'E' in this conversion` As Enak mentioned below, there is a `toPlainString()` method that doesn't use exponential form.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. But we need the output in number format not in String format. toPlainString() method returns String.

Comment: *Read the API.* https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html#doubleValue()

Comment: And update your question if you're looking for a specific format. Using the value in a `System.out.println()` statement implicitly tells the reader that you want a `String` since that's what a print statement typically uses.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding what `System.out.println()` does. The method inherently uses an objects `toString()` method when given a Object as a parameter. If you want to have the value formatted differently when displaying it's contents using `System.out.println()`, then you need to use a different method which formats the `String` representation of the Object differently which would be `toPlainString()` in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use setScale method for avoiding scientific notation 'E' during conversion from Double to BigDecimal. Follow the  below code snippet:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
    
 import org.apache.commons.lang3.math.NumberUtils;
    
    public class test {
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Double aDouble = NumberUtils.createDouble("345444330");
            System.out.println(BigDecimal.valueOf(aDouble.doubleValue()));//Output:3.4544433E+8
            BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal(aDouble).setScale(2);//Output:345444330.00 
            System.out.println(b);
    
        }
    
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Just look into the API. `BigDecimal` has a `toPlainString` method which

> Returns a string representation of this BigDecimal without an exponent field.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#toPlainString--

Comment: Need output in number format. Where as BigDecimal.toPlainString() return us String.

Comment: I don't get what you try to achieve here. If you want to calculate with it, just don't care about the String representation of it because it doesn't matter. If you want to print it, use the function mentioned by me.

Comment: What do you mean by "number format"? What _type_ do you want the output to be?

Comment: Hi Enak, After conversion from Double to BigDecimal we need to send the converted BigDecimal value in a response of an API. That's why we can't use BigDecimal.toPlainString() method as the client side will look for a BigDecimal value not a String value.

Comment: Then just send the `BigDecimal`. If you use any `Object` in `System.out.print` function, the `toString` method of the object gets called. The scientific notation is just for the representation as string. You will probably send a serialized `BigDecimal` and not a String. So don't care about the string represenation of it.